# R igraph millions row csv memory

Tags: r, csv, igraph

I have 1.2 million nodes data, 1.3 million edges data in csv files.

In nodes csv, have `id | label` columns. In edges csv have `source | target | edgeid` columns.

In edges section `source` is `id of node`, and also `target` is `id of another node`.

So I'm trying to create network graph in R. BTW this is my first shot on R.

```
library(igraph)
nodesData<-read.csv("nodes.csv",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE,sep="|",row.names=NULL)
edgesData<-read.csv("edges.csv",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE,sep="|",row.names=NULL)
relation <- data.frame(c(edgesData$source),c(edgesData$target))
g<-graph.data.frame(relation,directed = FALSE)
plot(g, layout=layout.kamada.kawai)
```

When I run that codes,

> Error in .Call(fn, graph, as.double(params$niter),
>   as.double(params$initemp),  :    At vector.pmt:130 : cannot init
>   vector, Out of memory

Gives me an error like that. Is it because of millions data? How can I handle that out of memory situation?

Also second question; is there a way to use a label(string) to target and source nodes for visualization?

Edit:

Data Example edges.csv

```
source|target|type|id|label|weight
1|2|Undirected|1|""|1
2|3|Undirected|2|""|1
3|4|Undirected|3|""|1
4|5|Undirected|4|""|1
6|7|Undirected|5|""|1
7|8|Undirected|6|""|1
8|9|Undirected|7|""|1
```

Comment: This data size should work fine, so it is something else. Can you share a small part of the data?

Comment: Hey Gabor, I added edges.csv data example. Also it continues up to 1.3 millions.

Comment: Wait, this error is coming the layout algorithm? Then yes, you cannot run the Kamada-Kawai algorithm on graphs of this size, as it works with adjacency matrices. Actually, graphs of this size are hard to visualize with any algorithm. I suggest you cluster the graph and then visualize the clusters.